# How do I implement the optimization function in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, deep-learning, convex-optimization

minΣ(||xi-X*ci||^2+ λ*||ci||),

s.t cii = 0,

where X is a matrix of shape d * n and C is of the shape n * n, xi and ci means a column of X and C separately.

X is known here and based on X we want to find C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with a loss like that you need to vectorize it, instead of working with columns:

```
loss = X - tf.matmul(X, C)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(loss))

reg_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(C), 0)  # L2 loss for each column
reg_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(reg_loss))

total_loss = loss + lambd * reg_loss
```

---

To implement the zero constraint on the diagonal of C, the best way is to add it to the loss with another constant `lambd2`:

```
reg_loss2 = tf.trace(tf.square(C))
total_loss = total_loss + lambd2 * reg_loss2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking of using tf.slice() to get a column of the matrix, do you think that would work as well? What is the mechanism of tf.slice()?

Comment: That would also work as the gradient would backpropagate to the original variable C (and X), but it would be very inefficient